# What happens when you over-contribute to Swiss Pillar 3a accounts?

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, pension, switzerland

If your total contribution to 3a accounts in a year is more than the limit (~6800 Fr. currently), what happens?

I could see several options:

a) the amount just carries over to the next year's contribution room, nothing else happens (i.e. the contribution limit is just a tax deduction limit);

b) the bank foundation or insurance company (which?) will reimburse you the exceeded amount but no penalty; or

c) a penalty tax is charged on the overcontribution until the amount is withdrawn (does the institution have to allow you to claim back overcontributed amount?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [www.vorsorge-3a.ch](https://www.vorsorge-3a.ch):

Those who have paid too much will receive a certificate from the responsible tax administration. With this certificate, the overpaid amount must be reclaimed from the bank or insurance company.

The recovery and thus the correction of the pillar 3a balance will be checked at the next tax assessment based on an account statement by the tax administration.

Overpaid amounts are considered free savings. They are offset as taxable assets (including interest) and assessed accordingly.